# Angularjs pass query parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, query-string

Right now I'm calling below code :

```
http://localhost:8081/cgi/#/home
```

And it takes me to my home page.

My app.js is :

```
angular.module('myModule', 
    ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap', 
     'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'])
.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider.when('/index', {
    controller : 'homeController',
    templateUrl : './app/views/index.html',
})

.when('/', {
    controller : 'homeController',
    templateUrl : './app/views/home.html'
})

.otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
});
}])
```

Now I need to add extra parameter "debug", which I can store in my controller and if it is there I need to call some function.

I have tried adding below to my app.js

```
    .when('/debug', {
    controller : 'homeController',
    templateUrl : './app/views/home.html',
    })
```

and below line to my controller

```
$scope.debug = $routeParams.debug === 'true' ? true : false;
console.log($scope.debug);
```

in my controller :

```
var app = angular.module('myModule');
app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $http, $route) {
    $scope.debug = $routeParams.debug === 'true' ? true : false;
    console.log($scope.debug);
}
```

Also please include url you think would work in answer as I can understand from where to start looking for either routeProvider or $location functionality

But page has now stopped loading and I don't have any clue how can I make it work.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject the $routeParams service to the controller. Just add it as a parameter to the controller function.

```
var app = angular.module('myModule');
app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $http, $route, $routeParams) {
    $scope.debug = $routeParams.debug === 'true' ? true : false;
    console.log($scope.debug);
}
```

**--- Update ---**

### Path

Use `$location.path() === '/debug'` to check if the current path is '/debug'. You need to inject the $location service.

```
var app = angular.module('myModule');
app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $http, $route, $location) {
    $scope.debug = $location.path() === '/debug';
    console.log($scope.debug);
}
```

### Query Param

This will allow you to check if there is a query parameter keyed "debug" with the value of "true".

```
http://localhost:8081/cgi/#/home?debug=true
```

```
var app = angular.module('myModule');
app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $http, $route, $location) {
    $scope.debug = $location.search().debug;
    console.log($scope.debug);
}
```

Comment: console.log("$routeParams.debug); 
Above gives undefined. How can I access debug as query parameter true or false?

Should i use http://localhost:8081/cgi/#/debug/true 

and

.when('/debug/true', { ... }

Comment: Oh, wait. I misunderstood what you were trying to do. Debug won't be passed in as a parameter because it is not setup in app.config properly. If all you want to do is check if the current path is /debug in the homeController, you can use the $location service.

Comment: @SiddharthShah Updated.

Comment: update worked. Thanks, also can you tell me if i want to add or call below url what should i do ? 
 localhost:8081/cgi/#/home?debug=true or  localhost:8081/cgi/#home?debug

Comment: @naiveTechie Updated my answer

Comment: thanks for all the clarification, i think i do understand $location little more now...